# wikipedia bots and captcha

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I see there are many [php (and other) frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Jarry1250/FrameworkTable) for writing wikipedia bots, but isn't captcha a problem? Or bots don't have to solve it (but that sounds like there's no point to having captcha in the first place...)? Or maybe i can make my prog stop and let me fill captcha in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properly-registered bots do not have to complete the captcha forms on Wikipedia. The [user group rights page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ListGroupRights) says that bots can, among other things:

> Perform captcha triggering actions
>   without having to go through the
>   captcha (skipcaptcha)

You will need to get your bot account added to the [bot group](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:ListUsers&group=bot) by a [bureaucrat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bureaucrats), and this usually takes place after acceptance by the [Bot Approvals Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bot_Approvals_Group).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware that Wikipedia had any sort of captcha... captcha for what? Editing articles? I'm pretty sure they encourage maintenance bots:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bots

Comment: Captchas are occasionally shown if you're adding links to a lot of pages.  (They can also be shown for account creation and if you have too many login attempts with the wrong password, but neither should affect a bot.)

Comment: ah, so it's to prevent brute-force pass cracking rather than to stop bots?